# While loop breaking prematurely

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am running in to an issue with this piece of code I've written to clean up and chunk text input in to 100-140 character lines while respecting word boundaries. This script is designed to parse by word or character so the function I'm referring to is wordQueue. So it basically takes input text, splits on newline, joins with a space and splits on space to give an array of "words". When the while loop shifts off a word, its added to the current chunk if chunk+word is less than the max chunk length. If its over the max length it pushes the current chunk in to the output array, resets the chunk and starts over. Each loop time it also checks to see if the remaining words left to be processed are less than the min chunk length when joined by a string. It breaks the loop and writes the file using the passed done callback.

This is not what happens. It gets through maybe 50 chunks before the script ends. The done callback isn't being called at all. I can see there are 44k+ words left in the array to be processed as well. I must be missing some piece of logic that is out of place. I will say this code was working but this just happened to be one of the scripts I didn't have in a repo, made some changes now it isn't working.

```
var
  fs = require('fs'),
  async = require('async'),
  _ = require('underscore');

var
  args = process.argv.splice(2),
  scriptInput,
  scriptOutput = [],
  csvFileName = args[0],
  config = {
    splitBy: args[1] || 'word',
  };

var re = {
  NL: /\n/,
  LR: /\r/,
  allTabs: /\t/g,
  multipleSpaces: /\s{2,}/,
  whiteSpace: /\s/g,
  leadingWhitespace: /^\s*/,
  trailingWhitespace: /\s$/,
  byCharBlacklist: /[a-zA-Z0-9!！@#%=\--—_?？.。,、，:：;"'“”|\$\^&*\(\)（）{}\\\/\[\]<>°…†]/g,
  byCharLineSplit: /.{1,52}/g
}

var
  cleanInput,
  wordQueue,
  charQueue,
  workQueue;

cleanInput = function (text) {
  return text
    // Normalize new lines
    .replace(re.LR, '')
    // Trim
    .replace(re.allTabs, ' ')
    .replace(re.multipleSpaces, ' ')
    .replace(re.leadingWhitespace, '')
    .replace(re.trailingWhitespace, '');
};

wordQueue = function (input, done) {
  var output = [], currentChunk = [], queue = input.split("\n").join(' ').split(' ');

  // While we have and words left to processed
  while (nextSegment = queue.shift()) {
    // If the currentChunk + current word will remain under max length, append to currentChunk
    if (currentChunk.join(' ').length + nextSegment.length <= config.maxChunkSize) {
      currentChunk.push(nextSegment);
      console.log("Gluing: %s", nextSegment);
      console.log("Words left: ", queue.length);
      console.log("\n");

    // If not, push the current currentChunk and reset for next cycle
    } else {
      output.push(currentChunk.join(' '));
      currentChunk = [];
      console.log('Pushing chunk "%s" in to output', currentChunk.join(' '));
      console.log("\n");
    }

    // If the remaining segments can't be glued to min length, break loop.
    if (queue.join(' ').length < config.minChunkSize) {
      console.log('End of data.');
      console.log('Writing output to file...');
      done(output.join("\n"));
      break;
    }
  }
};

charQueue = function (input, done) {
  var lines;

  input = input
    .split("\n")
    .join('')
    .replace(re.byCharBlacklist, '')
    .replace(re.whiteSpace, '');

  lines = input.match(re.byCharLineSplit);

  lines = _.map(lines, function (line) {
    return line.split('').join(' ');
  });

  done(lines.join("\n"));
};

/// RUN

config.minChunkSize = 100;
config.maxChunkSize = (config.splitBy == 'word') ? 140 : 105;

scriptInput = cleanInput(fs.readFileSync(csvFileName, 'utf8'));

workQueue = (config.splitBy == 'word') ? wordQueue : charQueue;

workQueue(scriptInput, function (output) {
  fs.writeFile(csvFileName+'.faster.csv', output, {encoding: 'utf16le'}, function (err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('File write complete: %s', csvFileName+'.faster.csv');
    });
});
```

Comment: Not the issue here, but `nextSegment` is an implicit global. That's fishy and bad practice, you should fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a dangerous condition for a loop: `nextSegment = queue.shift()`  You're expecting a value of `undefined` to end the loop, but note that the empty string will also evaluate to false.  Instead, I suggest using:

```
while ((nextSegment = queue.shift()) !== undefined) {
```

Comment: I think you meant to use `!==`.

Comment: Just to point it out, it's perfectly legal to have `undefined`s in an array, so even using this might not iterate through the entire array (which might or might not be wanted). The only safe way is using the `length` property.

Comment: @IngoBürk Given that the array was built by `split`ing a string, we can assume it will not contain any `undefined`s.  In the general case I agree with you, though.